# Multipoint evaluation of a given polynomial

Tags: polynomial-time-reductions, fast-fourier-transform

You are given a polynomial of degree n. We have to find the value of the polynomial at n different points in O(n(log(n))^2). The answer should be modulo 998244353.
I have read various blogs on it and a [research paper](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/CAG/theses/justine.pdf) but none could help me implement it.
If anyone could provide some insight it would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome, that's an interesting question. Can you clarify the following in your question? (1) How is the polynomial represented? (2) What do you mean, "we have to find the value of the polynomial at n different points in O(n(log(n))^2)"? Is the input a list of n values, and the output should be a list of n values of the polynomials?